# Get Auth User ID Laravel

Tags: laravel, authentication, breeze

I Made Laravel Project And install the Breeze package for multi authentication And the Create a guard call admin in order to control user assess to dashboard It works fine Here is the route

```
Route::get('/dashbord',[AdminController::class, 'Dashbord'])
    ->name('admin.dashbord')
    ->middleware('Admin');

Route::get('/profile/edit',[AdminProfileSettings::class, 'index'])
    ->name('admin.profile.settings')
    ->middleware('Admin');
```

Here Is the middleware

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
{
    if(!Auth::guard('admin')->check()) {
        return redirect()->route('login_form')->with('error','please Login First');
    }
    return $next($request);
}
```

This code works fine but the problem is when I log in to the dashboard and try to get admin ID to admin.profile.settings route it wont get the Id, I Passed the logged admin id by using AdminProfileSettings controller like this

```
public function index()
{
    $id=Auth::user()->id;
    $adminData = Admin::find($id);
    return view('admin.admin_profile_settings',compact('adminData'));
}
```

But, when I try to access it in the `admin.admin_profile_settings` view it show me this error:

> Trying to get property 'id' of non-object

But, if I use `$adminData = Admin::find(1);` it get the Id without any problem but when I try to get auth user id it show me the error and if I have logged in using default guard this error wont show but it get the `id` from users table

Answer (score 1):

You're not using the `auth:admin` middleware, so the `Auth` facade is going to pull the user from the default guard defined in the config (which is `web`, unless you've changed it).

Without using the `auth:admin` middleware, you'll need to specify the guard for which to get the user.

```
$adminUser = Auth::guard('admin')->user();
```

---

Note 1: if you have the `$request` variable, you can also pull the user off of the `$request` with `$request->user()`, instead of reaching out to the Auth facade. It's just a matter of preference. The `user()` method also takes a guard as a parameter, if needed.

```
$adminUser = $request->user('admin');
```

Note 2: the `user()` method (Auth and request) returns the fully hydrated model. There is no need to get the id and re-retrieve the model.